# How to prove all connected graphs with even number of edges and without loop and multiple edges can be divided into pairs of adjacent edges?

Tags: graph-theory

First I try to use induction.

Way1 :
I think this it like repeat deleting two adjancent edges in graph.
the two delete edge contain three point,supposed they are a,b,c,there are three cases:

1. If (a,b) (a,c) exist but (b,c) not exist.If delete (a,b)(a,c),the
   remained graph is still a graph with even edges
2. If (a,b) (b,c) exist but (a,c) not exist. If delete (a,b)(b,c),remained a graph withm even edges
3. If there is a cycle , such as (a,b)(b,c)(a,c). this has two cases

   case 2.1  after deleting, G is still connected , this is ok
   case 2.2  after deleting, G become two conponent G1 and G2,for
   example,if delete (a,c) and (b,c) ,and c has no another edge to the
   conponent which contains vertice a and vertice b. this again be two
   case.

   ```
    case 2.2.1 Both G1 and G2 has even edges, this is ok   
    case 2.2.2 Both G1 and G2 has odd edges, this is bad!!!!
   ```

I don't know how to prove in case 2.2 so I come to another way.

Way2 :
 First find a edge e1 and then we should find another e2 to match it.After deleting e1 e2 ,there are two case

case 1 G is connected, ok
 case 2 w(G)=2, suppose G-e1 = G1 + e2 + G2
    , then in G1 must has even edges and G2 has odd edges. the most
    important one is to find a e2 in G2 .

I don't know how to do when G2-e2 become two unconnect odd conponent!!

can anyone help me ?
Thanks~

Comment: Prove that there is always at least one pair of adjacent edges that can be deleted without disconnecting the graph.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: That statement isn't true, though.  Consider a tree with an even number of edges, then *any* edge deletion disconnects the graph.  (Some of the resulting connected components might consist of single vertices, but they still exist.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson - in this problem only the edges matter. It should be understood that removing edges includes moving any isolated vertices created.

Answer (score 1):

I got an idea ! use strong induction . suppose for all G with 2n vertice satisfied the statement.
Then we shuld proof it is true when |V|=2(n+1)
when |G| = (2n+1) , just like add two edge e1 , e2 and we delete e1 and e2 ,either one pair or two pair of edges,then we get G', there are three cases in G':

1. w(G') = 1 : G' is connected ,then we G' with 2n or 2(n-1) vertice satisfied condition
2. w(G') = 2 : If both two conponent of G' are odd edges ,we can let e1 and its adjacent edge choose one edge in their adjacet component ,and both conponent will conotain even edges ; if both conponent contains even edge,it satisfy;
3. w(G') = 3 : G' = G'' + (e1,ei) + (e2,ej) , G'' contains be even edges

to conclude G with 2(n+1) satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 1):

In any tree with more than $2$ vertices one of the following must happen:

- A leaf is connected to a vertex of degree $2$
- two leaves are adjacent to the same vertex.

Proof: Suppose neither of these things happen. mark every leaf of the tree and then remove all of them, we obtain a graph in which every vertex has degree at least $2$. (notice that if there are more than two vertices then not every vertex is a leaf).

Suppose that there is a counterexample to the theorem we desire to prove. Let $G$ be a counterexample with the least possible number of vertices, and among the counterexamples with the least possible number of vertices pick a counterexample with the least possible number of edges.

Pick a spanning subgraph $T$ of $G$.

Suppose that a leaf $l$ is connected to a vertex $v$ of degree $2$ (suppose $w$ is the other neighbout of $v$). Notice that after removing vertices $(l,v)$ and $(v,w)$ we get a graph in which only vertices $l$ and $v$ might be separated from the rest (but even then there is no edge between them). So we obtain a graph in which every component has an even number of edges, a contradiction.

Suppose that two leaves $l$ and $m$ contain a common neighbour $v$. If the edge $(l,m)$ exists in $G$, then after removing edges $(l,m)$ and $(l,v)$ we obtain a graph in which the only possible separated vertex is $l$, this would be a contradiction because every connected component of the resulting graph would have an even number of edges. On the other hand, if $(l,m)$ does not exist in $G$, after removing edges $(l,v)$ and $(m,v)$ we obtain a graph in which the only possible separated edges are $l$ and $m$, but there is no edge between them. So we obtain a graph in which every component has an even number of edges, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If suffices to prove that in every connected graph $G(V,E)$ with $|E|\overset{2}{\equiv} 0$, one can set directions for every edge $e$ in $G$ which for evey vertex $v$, $d^{+}(v)$ is an even number. Then we would take pairs of exiting edges from every vertex, as a path with length of $2$. Here is an example:[image: A sample for division of graph to paths of length 2]

First, set an arbitrary direction for every edge in $G$. If there is no vertex $v$ such that $d^{+}(v) \overset{2}{\equiv} 1$ , we are done.
so suppose that there exists a vertex $v$ with $d^{+}(v)$ being odd. from a well-known lemma, we know that $\sum_{v \in V} d^{+}(v) = |E| \overset{2}{\equiv} 0$. Hence $\exists \, u\in V, u \neq v: d^{+}(u) \overset{2}{\equiv} 1$. Since $G$ is connected, there is an [undirected] path from $v$ to $u$. We invert the direction of every edge in this path. It is easy to see that the parity of exiting degree of vertices in this path, despite $u$ and $v$, remain unchanged; and now $d^{+}(u)\overset{2}{\equiv}d^{+}(v)\overset{2}{\equiv}0$. As $V$ is finite, this operation must end. Thus every vertex in $G$ has an even number of exiting edges, done.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with an idea : if I reconstruct a new graph like this:
take all edges in G as vertice in G' , if e1 and e2 have common vertice, then in G' , v1 and v2 have a edge.
then our question become : matching a connected graph G' with even vertice.
This is easy, a connected tree has a subtree , then we delete vertice from all its leaves . QED!!

Comment: yearh , this is not true, in such a tree a->b->c and b->d